# File Upload throught HTTPS

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, https, upload

I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to write it down, but simply,

I was wondering, if I have standard php uploading

```
move_uploaded_file()
```

if I install https on the apache server, do I need to do anything to the php code for the upload part, so php send the file securely, or all the upload data now encrypted and secured?

Comment: nothing to do on server. just check you are posting your form on `HTTPS` url

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make sure that your upload forms' action lists the https endpoint.